# Booting up - Can't get my Toshiba portable hard drive to load up - no icon visible?

Tags: boot

When I try to load my portable hard drive to back up - it does not load. It looks and acts likes it is being read ie the light flashes - then the light is fixed and no icon appears on screen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you insert the drive please and go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `dmesg | tail --lines=40&&lsusb`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question so we can see what exact hardware you have. Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Answer (score 0):

If your portable hard drive is formatted to NTFS, then you should install ntfs support to your ubuntu:

```
    sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

and then connect your drive again.